# Codeigniter - pass result from model to controller into a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass the contents of a column Ext "language" from the database to my controller that contains the various languages: "en, fr, etc". 
This allows me to send emails with the correct translation of the language user. 
That is, in my model I have to pass the result to the controller and store it in a variable called $ language. 
This variable contains "en, fr etc. ..": $ message = sprintf ($ this-> lang-> line ('messaggio.email'), $ language, $ key);

The sending of the email works perfectly, except that I can not set the variable $ language. 
I get this error: 
"Severity: Notice 
Message: Array to string conversion "

How can I set the variable $ language?

**This is the model:**

```
public function get_dati() {
    $this->load->database();

   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM temp_users ");

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        echo $row['lingua'];
    }


    $res = array(
        'lingua' => $row['lingua']
    );

    return $res;
}
```

**This is my controller:**

```
    $this->load->model('model_users_azienda');
$language['teste'] = $this->model_users_azienda->get_dati();
/ / Here I insert the content from database in the variable $ language
$message = sprintf($this->lang->line('messaggio.email'), $language, $key);
```

Comment: You cannot echo out in the method `public function get_dati()`. Also check the sprintf string `messaggio.email` because that may be trying to use the $language as a string not an array.

Comment: I felt if I was printing the result.

Comment: how can I convert an array to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work. The model function returns an array. So you need to get the language using proper key from array.

```
$this->load->model('model_users_azienda');
$lang = $this->model_users_azienda->get_dati();
/ / Here I insert the content from database in the variable $ language
$message = sprintf($this->lang->line('messaggio.email'), $lang['lingua'], $key);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! 
I returns the value of the query "En, En, Fr, etc. ..." instead of "en, fr etc. .." with an initial capital letters, 
I'll try to figure out why, Thanks again!